# How do I tell Prometheus' Alertmanager to send email through Gmail's SMTP server

Tags: smtp, gmail, smtp-auth, prometheus

I would like Prometheus to send emails from a Gmail (Gapps) account when metrics cross certain thresholds.
In the [Alertmanager config docs](http://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#email-receiver-email_config), there's no mention of passwords.  How do I authenticate to the SMTP server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with the fields `auth_username`, `auth_password` and `auth_identity` in the config file.

There's a full guide at http://www.robustperception.io/sending-email-with-the-alertmanager-via-gmail/

Make sure you're using a very recent alertmanager, 0.1.1 won't work.

Comment: I think there must be something more required.  Email notifications still  fail with the error, "Must issue a STARTTLS command first"

Comment: To further clarify for anyone reading this - at the time this question was written there was a bug in the Prometheus code that prevented Email alerts from working with TLS servers.  
- at the time of this comment, there is a fix committed to the github repo, but there has not been a release that includes that fix yet.  At the moment, one must build Prometheus from source to use email alerts with gmail (or another SMTP host that requires TLS).

Comment: Also note that the location of the config has changed, it's now in the config file rather than environment variable. The guide has been updated, but a release has yet to be made.

Comment: @brian-brazil Is that config is still correct in 2018?

Comment: @ipeacocks, yes, just tested, this still works.
I would like to `note` that it is against best practices to use environment variables for secrets, like the app password/token. @brian-brazil 's write-up will change out the variables as it writes the config.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following template in your alert manager configuration file and change the values according to your requirement.

```yaml
config:
  global:
    resolve_timeout: 5m
  route:
    group_by: ['job']
    group_wait: 30s
    group_interval: 5m
    repeat_interval: 1h
    receiver: 'tech-email'
    routes:
    - match:
        alertname: Watchdog
      receiver: 'null'
  receivers:
  - name: 'tech-email'
    email_configs:
    - to: 'to-email@example.com'
      from: 'from-email@outlook.com'
      auth_username: **********
      auth_password: **********
      require_tls: yes
      smarthost: **********
      send_resolved: true
  - name: 'null'
```

For **auth_username**, **auth_password** and **smarthost**, you can generate the credentials from SES or any provider.